# How to authenticate on Google oauthplayground

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-oauth

little context before the problem: I want to use Google Home to connect with my account (that I manage on my server) in order to manipulate my APIs.

So I strictly follow the implicit flow for account linking, [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow).

When I tried it on [OAuthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) in Client-side / Custom / my endpoint. I am redirect to my server, authorize google and got 404 on google side.

May I miss something in the documentation ?

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have to redirect on https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground#access_token=$token&token_type=$response.

Thank you Google :)